# Is it possible to make an Android App that records Audio while taking fotos?

Tags: java, android, windows, audio, camera

I've read somewhere that it isn't still possible to record Audio while using the Camera function on Android phones. But this source was kind of outdated. 
I've also read, that this is possible on Iphone.
But I need this function for Android to create an App.

Can anybody say more to that?
Is there a possibility on Android to archive that in an Application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why not.  They don't share the same hardware.  Even if not, you could easily fake it by recording video (which also records sound) and just taking the first still image of the video as your photo.

Comment: Good answer Gabe. @gabe sechan

Comment: Thats a way I allready thought about myself. Wouldn't be the nicest solution, but if there is no other way around, I'll have to do it that way. I guess I'll have to try it that way.

Comment: Well I'd just try it the normal way first.  I can't think of any reason why it wouldn't work, so long as you use the Camera class and take the picture yourself (don't do it via intent).